# Blob Upload Hanging

Tags: google-app-engine

I was wondering if anything had changed recently in relation to uploading blobs to appengine from external applications? What used to work perfectly only 3 months ago is now hanging when doing a http post to upload the blob.

The code (see below) which was working fine previously consists in fetching a pull queue from AppEngine (using the REST API), doing some stuff with this task received and then uploading back the result as a Blob on AppEngine. The url to upload the blob to is created by appengine using  blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload");

and is of the form:

```
      http://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6aAHnkuS4ngyRJDn7urFFZeBxb_-3P-r7RY9udMvRjLWkEZNJMgUX1DFczNVi-NhIxcFat2AEPXs2IRJ0AOmznSMgcrCKmL7mGAmS7nqtr-UyYFkglD88BwCfzIui9M2yez7DSQ/ALBNUaYAAAAAUGRlEwpeGEc5ozp8Z8sDO33qgCi2AiIE/
```

I had a look at the logs on AppEngine and it seems like the servlet in charge of /upload isn't being triggered.

I'm honestly out of ideas at this stage, any help would be greatly appreciated ! :-)

Cheers,

Killian

```
 public boolean uploadAsBlob(String dataToWrite, String uploadURL) {

 try {

      BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFileLocation));

      bufferedWriter.write(dataToWrite);

      bufferedWriter.newLine();

      bufferedWriter.close();

      MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

      entity.addPart(blobFileName, new FileBody(new File(tempFileLocation)));

      HttpPost method = new HttpPost(uploadURL);

      method.setEntity(entity);

      final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

      HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);

      DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);


      //It hangs at the following line!

      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method);

      if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

           logger.info("Uploaded blob to url: " + uploadURL);

           return true;

      } else {

           logger.warning("Couldn't upload blob to url: " + uploadURL);

      }



      } catch (Exception e) {

      logger.warning("Exception " + e.getMessage() + " occured while uploading blob to url:" + uploadURL);

      logger.warning("Couldn't upload blob to url: " + uploadURL);

      }

      return false;

      }
```

Comment: Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong there? Would be of major help ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that GAE has recently started to keep any GET parameters when invoking  blobstoreService.createUploadUrl(). In my case:

`http://www.myapp.com/BG?_=1354631578951`

With this (unexpected) parameter, the created URL was:

`http://www.myapp.com/_ah/upload/?_=1354631578951/AMmfu6YgVPoJzWXdbf70k6J0zdjEeRnnRJ2PYCb3Jgdwk3SqmKEnFyKgy_17CKwiqbC2HyO-FlPVX-C53W0LjHSywaq7YmLegD97uU-GrpWRdBdWbfKf0Dk/ALBNUaYAAAAAUL4L8iDS5E99f3Wky2p59wWpCD84AqoP/`

Notice that the '_' parameter is still there. Removing the parameter (or maybe moving from GET to POST) fixed the problem.